# What is 到 doing in the sentence 他可能会到地址目录中查找?

Tags: grammar

A [Jukuu.com](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8A%9E%E6%B3%95) example sentence:

> 还有一种办法，他可能会到地址目录中查找。
>   Alternatively, he could look the address up in a directory.
>   <sub>Hái yǒuyī zhǒng bànfǎ, tā kěnéng huì dào dìzhǐ mùlù zhōng cházhǎo.</sub>

Everything here makes sense to me except 到.

**Question**: What is 到 doing in the sentence 他可能会到地址目录中查找?

Breaking it down:

- 还有一种[办法](http://dict.cn/%E5%8A%9E%E6%B3%95) = still have one kind of solution
- 他[可能](http://dict.cn/%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD)[会](http://dict.cn/%E4%BC%9A) (tā kěnéng huì) = he possibly can ...
- [到](http://dict.cn/%E5%88%B0) (dào) = to arrive (???)
- [地址](http://dict.cn/%E5%9C%B0%E5%9D%80)[目录](http://dict.cn/%E7%9B%AE%E5%BD%95) (dìzhǐ mùlù) = "address table of contents" likely means "address book"
- 中 (zhōng) = within
- [查找](http://dict.cn/%E6%9F%A5%E6%89%BE) (cházhǎo) = to look up

It seems possible that I might be breaking this up incorrectly: instead 到地址 go together as "destination address", which is separate from 目录.

Comment: 到 is used preverbially as "coverb" (CCG use)：more examples:  您可以到电梯旁的指南上查找。你到哪儿去？他下午到医院看病去。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

到。。。。中 quite literally says 'to .... in'

Chinese nearly always has these double-barrelled prepositions, like here, 到。。。中 = in, into

还有一种办法，他可能会[到地址目录中]查找。

人们应该将正确的理论应用[到实践中]。

到事业中去
到打字机中
到空气中

Answer (score 1):

到...中 in this context could be interpreted as **'get into'**.

他可能会到地址目录中查找?: he might get into the address catalogue to have a search.

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking the sentence down correctly.

[到](http://www.zdic.net/z/16/xs/5230.htm) might mean `go to`, for indicating *where* to do sth. So "到地址目录中查找" means "to look up in the address book".